# Hide product description

Tags: opencart

How can I hide product description when the description is long in Opencart (product page) to reduce the load product page, but after clicking on the detail link then came out a full description.
In image you can see Example, Sorry for my bad english, Thanks!
Here is a link to example image [example](http://imglink.ru/pictures/10-07-12/cc935fe9b5c14a7b7bc65932e3b9d623.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why not just truncate it? It will force it to be the right length for you every time!**

Go to catalog/controller/product/category.php and when you see

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result['image']) {
        $image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_product_height'));
    } else {
        $image = false;
    }
```

Add this next:

```
function truncate($description, $tLimit="20", $break=" ", $pad="...")
{
  if(strlen($string) <= $tlimit) return $string;

  if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $tlimit))) {
    if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) {
      $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad;
    }
   }

   return $description;
 }
```

Feel free to change the variables:

**$tLimit** is how many letters you want to allow it.

**$break** is where you want it to cut off, right now it is set to cut off at the next space. You can have it interrupt words if you like by putting $break=""

**$pad** is what you want it to show after it cuts off the text.

**If you really want no description to show at all** Then I recommend still doing something similar to the original script.

```
function getDescriptionLength($description, $tLimit="20")
{
  if(strlen($string) <= $tlimit) return $string;

  else {
    $description = NULL;
  }

  return $description;
}
```